# Каким образом мы хотим обрабатывать дефекты на Мете?

Tags: обсуждение

Как мы знаем, Stack Overflow – американская компания. В большинстве своем, сотрудники знают лишь английский язык. Как результат, существует некоторая сложность в отслеживании и исправлении дефектов на международных сайтах сети Stack Exchange.

В этой связи спешу вынести на рассмотрение сообщества наиболее оптимальные варианты публикации дефектов на Мете.

Пожалуйста, если у вас есть альтернативные идеи, опубликуйте их в ответе на этот вопрос. Было бы здорово выбрать наиболее оптимальный для сообщества и компании подход!

Comment: И вообще, мы хотим чтобы дефектов не было. А не обрабатывать их :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Публикация дефектов на русском и английском языках

Участники сообщества размещают сообщения о дефектах на Мете русскоязычного Stack Overflow  одновременно на русском и английском языках. (Либо только на русском, а другие участники, увидя только русскоязычное описание дефекта, могут добавить перевод через правку вопроса.)

**Минусы**

- Наличие непонятного иностранного языка на нашей любимой русскоязычной Мете!
- Необходимость перевода дефекта на английский язык.

**Плюсы**

- Разработчики видят такие дефекты и могут их понять, а как результат, быстро исправить. В системе имеется специальная служебная страница, которая показывает дефекты со всех Мет (вопросы, отмеченные меткой [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82)).
- В этом случае пропадает наличие дополнительной стадии переноса дефекта с Меты, упрощается отслеживание и проверка работоспособности исправлений.

Comment: О, как получилось: `на Мете Stack Overflow на русском на русском и`. В кавычки что ли взять надо.

Comment: @alexolut Великий и могучий!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, можно прост одновременно поместить после на русском перед на русском :-)

Comment: Не очень понимаю, чем перевод Google.Translate от автора репорта о баге лучше перевода тем же гуглом потенциальным фиксером бага. Я какие-то общие баги стараюсь кидать на [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) вообще. Но специфические для ruSO пишу сюда. Хотя, может быть их и на Meta.SE можно с какой-нибудь меткой типа `localization` или `russian-stackoverflow`. Я всё это к тому, что две версии (рус+англ) обычно не требуется иметь.

Comment: @alexolut, Например тем, что разработчики просто смотрят по-быстрому, а не исправляют дефекты целенаправленно, поэтому если есть перевод, он может посмотреть, а если нет - то скорее пропустит :)

Comment: @alexolut С MSE проблема в том, что они все дефекты о Stack Overflow на русском будут мигрировать на нашу Мету. В сети принято публиковать проблемы каждого сообщества на своей мете. На MSE, теоретически, должны идти только дефекты относящиеся ко всем сайтам сразу.

Comment: @Grundy можно же поставить Chrome с автоматическим переводом страниц :)

Comment: @alexolut Существует вероятность, что силами сообщества (или меня) перевод описания дефекта будет более понятный.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ну я тогда не очень понимаю смысла существования метки [`russian-stackoverflow`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russian-stackoverflow).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ну если Вы будете переводить на постоянной основе и достаточно оперативно, то это, конечно, хорошо. Но вот, будете ли? :) Кстати, перевод можно спрятать под спойлер, чтобы он не мешал русскоговорящему участнику.

Comment: @alexolut Наверное, для подобный вопросов: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276523/

Comment: @alexolut Я в любом случае их перевожу уже сейчас. В локальной базе все дефекты на английском!

Comment: @alexolut Я, скорее, кардинально против английского языка на нашей Мете. Ибо это наша Мета и нечего тут английскому языку делать. В сети достаточно Мет, где можно на английском писать.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky если английскому тут не место, то надо тогда и комментарии переводить недавние от m0sa, а это только модератор может.

Comment: @alexolut, перевести может кто угодно. Плюс, повод выпросить нормальные спойлеры)))

Comment: @Qwertiy перевести комментарии?

Comment: @alexolut, я о вопросах и ответах говорил. Комментарии можно продублировать на другом языке. Хотя, не уверен, что стоит.

Comment: @Qwertiy вопросы/ответы понятно, что можно перевести через ревизии, это даже не обсуждалось. А про комменты это из реальной ситуации [недавней](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4068/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%83%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-app-store#comment13392_4068).

Answer (score 1):

#### Публикация дефектов в стиле «как раньше»

Участники сообщества размещают дефекты на Мете, после чего, дефекты в индивидуальном порядке отправляются разработчикам.

**Плюсы**

- Дефект разместить крайне легко.

**Минусы**

- Нет возможности понять кто и когда исправит дефект.
- Крайне проблематично отследить, что дефект был исправлен и подтвердить его отсутсвие.

Comment: Вот буквально только что [разработчик отписался](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3714/176217) о проделанной работе.

Comment: @alexolut Это скорее исключение, чем правило, когда ребята на личной инициативе переводят вопросы через Google Translate ([смотри другое предложение](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4084/6)).

Answer (score -6):

#### Перенести все дефекты на Meta Stack Exchange

Всегда просить участников сообщества, публикующих дефекты на Мета Stack Overflow на русском, перенести вопросы на Meta Stack Exchange.

**Минусы**

- Не до конца понятно, как будет реагировать на вопросы про русскоязычное сообщество ребята с MSE.
- Требование публикации вопроса только на английском языке.
- Отсутствие базы знаний о сайте. Дефекты не всегда являются дефектами. Собирая на Мете обсуждения реализации, мы собираем знания о том, как работает сайт для будущих участников.

**Плюсы**

- Отсутствие каких–либо проблем касающихся дефектов на нашей Мете.
- Наши дефект будут более видны мировому сообществу, что, возможно, приведет к их исправлению наряду с другими дефектами движка.

Comment: В этом случае нужно будет ещё и запрещать постинг новых дефектов по-русски, а это вообще может привести к тому, что дефект не будет опубликован.

Comment: @alexolut Совершенно верно!

Comment: [`С MSE проблема в том, что они все дефекты о Stack Overflow на русском будут мигрировать на нашу Мету. В сети принято публиковать проблемы каждого сообщества на своей мете`](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4082/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5/4085?noredirect=1#comment13416_4084) Если это так, то как можно реализовать текущий вариант?

Comment: @alexolut Теоретически – да, по средствам революции на MSE.

Comment: Имхо, маловероятно. Нужно сначала [этого](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3793/stack-overflow-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-super-user#comment12202_3793) добиться.