# Новый процесс публикации дефектов и предложений на Мете

Tags: поддержка, faq

Голосованием в вопросе [«Каким образом мы хотим обрабатывать дефекты на Мете?»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4082/) сообщество определило новый способ публикации дефектов и предложений на Мете.

> Для дефектов, касающихся движка, которые, как вы полагаете, требуют вмешательства разработчиков, следует предоставлять два описания дефекта на русском и на английском языках. Аналогичное правило справедливо и для предложений.

**Примечание**

Если вы по какой–либо причине (например, в силу знаний английского, отсутствия желания писать на иностранном языке или любой другой) хотите опубликовать дефект или предложение только на русском языке – этого достаточно. Время от времени, другие участники сообщества будут проходиться по таким публикациям и добавлять описание на английском языке.

**Примечание 2**

Если, по вашему мнению, дефект, или просто вопрос, можно разрешить силами сообщества – англоязычное описание не требуется!

**Примечание 3**

Английский язык в любых других случая кроме дефектов или предложений на Мете Stack Overflow на русском недопустим. Для публикаций дефектов и предложений только на английском языке, пожалуйста используйте [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

---

Если вы увидели вопрос, потенциально адресованный разработчикам, который содержит описание только на русском языке, пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь добавить описание на английском языке!

Comment: Можно ввести метку [meta-tag:требует-перевода] для сообщений, которые нужно перевести.

Comment: У меня была ещё другая мысль (ещё не озвучивал, и не знаю, имеет ли теперь смысл), создавать переведенное сообщение на Meta.SE и указывать обязательные ссылки между ними. Возможно, это внесёт некоторые сложности при синхронизации вопросов, но зато уменьшит наличие английского текста непосредственно на ruSO.

Comment: @NickVolynkin идея хорошая, но надо понимать когда ставить и снимать эту метку. Например можно её снять после перевода, но нужно не забыть добавить при внесении изменений в русской части текста.

Comment: @alexolut если разработчики точно читают нашу Мету, то наверное труд по дублированию вопросов будет лишним. Ставить метку можно когда видишь непереведённый баг-репорт (включая свой), а снимать — когда перевод выполнен.

Comment: @NickVolynkin это простой случай. При дополнении вопроса нужно и перевод дополнять.

Comment: Ещё надо учитывать момент закрытия как "дубликат", насколько я понимаю, этого нельзя будет сделать для межсайтовых вопросов.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Оличная идея!

Comment: @NickVolynkin идея действительно отличная! Я даже задумался, не стоит ли что-то такое же ввести на основном сайте, для случаев, когда человек задал вопрос, а точно такой же с ответом нашёлся на, скажем, enSO. Оставить ссылку на "английский дубликат" и поставить метку, чтобы кто-нибудь занялся переводом.

Comment: @D-side Даже [публикация на Мете](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2983/) есть об этом!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ну, там есть про ссылку, но я про применение этого механизма с целью расширения базы знаний. Для ситуаций, когда у исходного вопроса (на русском) ответов нет, а у ассоциированного есть. Надо как-то сориентировать людей, готовых переводить ответы, какими вопросами они могут заняться. Вот.

Comment: А разрешено ли дублировать дефекты и на русском, и на английском?

Comment: Всё ещё остаётся много вопросов по данному способу публикации дефектов. Мне кажется, нужно создать пошаговую инструкцию, описывающую процесс создания сообщения о дефекте на Мете. Как быть с заголовком, как должны быть расположены английская и русская части текста в сообщении, как быть с картинками и т.п.